# Collapse text by group by ID in Python

Tags: python

I have dataset with 3 variables, I want to create a new variable or update the old varibale `Key` which paste element if groupby `Question` and `Value` duplicated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Question":["Q008D02","Q008D02","Q008D02","Q008D02","Q008D03","Q008D03","Q008D03","Q008D03","Q008D03","Q008D04","Q008D04","Q008D04","Q008D04","Q008D04","Q008D04","Q008D04"],
               "Value" :[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,2,3,4,4,4],"Key": ["Text 1","Text 2","Text 3","Text 4","Answer1","Answer2","Answer3","Answer4","Answer5","Check1","Check2","Check3","Check4","Check5","Check6","Check7"]},
             columns = ["Question","Value","Key"])
   Question  Value      Key
0   Q008D02      1   Text 1
1   Q008D02      2   Text 2
2   Q008D02      3   Text 3
3   Q008D02      4   Text 4
4   Q008D03      1  Answer1
5   Q008D03      2  Answer2
6   Q008D03      3  Answer3
7   Q008D03      4  Answer4
8   Q008D03      4  Answer5
9   Q008D04      1   Check1
10  Q008D04      2   Check2
11  Q008D04      2   Check3
12  Q008D04      3   Check4
13  Q008D04      4   Check5
14  Q008D04      4   Check6
15  Q008D04      4   Check7
```

I want the output

```
   Question Value Key
0   Q008D02 1   Text 1
1   Q008D02 2   Text 2
2   Q008D02 3   Text 3
3   Q008D02 4   Text 4
4   Q008D03 1   Answer1
5   Q008D03 2   Answer2
6   Q008D03 3   Answer3
7   Q008D03 4   Answer4,Answer5
8   Q008D04 1   Check1
9   Q008D04 2   Check2,Check3
10  Q008D04 3   Check4
11  Q008D04 4   Check5,Check6,Check7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby.agg`, and specify `','.join` as the aggregation function which pastes Key from the same group together:

```
df.groupby(['Question', 'Value']).agg({'Key':','.join}).reset_index()
```

[image]